# When I came over with the mouse div, div show hidden for jquery

Tags: jquery, html, web

```js
 if ($("#example").mouseover) {
      $("#test").show(1500);
 }
```

```css
#example{
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
}

#test{
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id='example'>MENU</a>
<div id="test">
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When clicked on a link, I want to display a div as a dropdow menu. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: English is very poor , I'm sorry

Comment: @erkaner Use English Language only in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#example{
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
}

#test{
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
    display:none;
}


<a id='example'>MENU</a>
<div id="test">
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item1</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$("#example").mouseover(function() {
      $("#test").show('slow');
}).mouseout(function() {
      $("#test").hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".example").on('mouseover',function(){
  $(".test").show(1500);
});
```

and change

```
<div hidden="hidden" class="test">
```

to

```
<div class="test">
```

and use display:none;

```
.test{

    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
    display:none;


}
```